# Any idea why append in loop is not working.?

Tags: python

Hi I am new to coding so need your help.
Any idea why append in loop is not working.?

code:
x = ['ab', 'cd']
for i in x:
x.append(i.upper())
print(x)

**Expected output:**
['ab', 'cd', 'AB', 'CD']

but not getting any output, and compiler runs out of ram

Thanks

Comment: The issue with your code is that you are modifying the list x while iterating over it, which can lead to an infinite loop. try and  use x.extend([i.upper() for i in x])